# Converting a tensorflow object into a jpeg on local drive

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/deepdream):

in order to create a python program that will create a deep-dream style img and save in onto disk. I thought that changes to the following lines should do the trick:

```
  img = run_deep_dream_with_octaves(img=original_img, step_size=0.01)

  display.clear_output(wait=True)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, base_shape)
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img/255.0, dtype=tf.uint8)
  tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
  fname = '2.jpg'
  with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
      enc = tf.io.encode_jpeg(img)
      fwrite = tf.io.write_file(tf.constant(fname), enc)
      result = sess.run(fwrite)'
```

the key line being encode_jpeg, however this gives me the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 246, in <module>
  enc = tf.io.encode_jpeg(img)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
  packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_image_ops.py", line 1496, in encode_jpeg
  name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
  packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 470, in 
  _apply_op_helper
  preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
  packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1465, in convert_to_tensor
  raise RuntimeError("Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without "
  RuntimeError: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

Comment: Did you miss the indentation after the session, or is it a formatting issue here?

Comment: sorry. formatting issue.

Comment: which version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: i have the following line in my code: 'import tensorflow as tf '     so ver 2 i believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply convert the "img" tensor into numpy array and then save it as you have eager execution enabled (its enabled by default in tf 2.0)

So, the modified code for saving the image will be:

```
img = run_deep_dream_with_octaves(img=original_img, step_size=0.01)

display.clear_output(wait=True)
img = tf.image.resize(img, base_shape)
img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img/255.0, dtype=tf.uint8)
fname = '2.jpg'
PIL.Image.fromarray(np.array(img)).save(fname)
```

You don't have to use sessions in tf2.0 to get the values from tensor.